# If formfield is not empty then stop execution of script

Tags: php

I have a contact form and it should send me an email with content using php mail.

To avoid some spambots I have a hidden field in the form.

Now I want to check if the field is empty, and if not stop the script from sending the mail.

I request the content of the field into the $bot variable

So what I want to to is something like

if $bot not empty then don't go on else execute the rest of the script

Please help a beginner

Regards

Anders

Answer (score 1):

Use the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

```
<?php
if (empty($bot)) {
    // send your mail here
} else {
    // redirect, the field is not empty!
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **JAVASCRIPT**. it would definitely be helpful to apply anytype of checks you want.

if you only use the php code on the next page. then it would not be a good strategy.